# python pandas dataframe talib KAMA function below breaks the execution seems missed certain key input here

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, ta-lib

In the below line, trying to make the KAMA function to return a calculated value
the stockdata is a dataframe that contains OHLC value, here VClose =stockdata['Close']
To calculate the KAMA value and to store it in the same dataframe list , tried using numpyarray as well here. the "hakamaper" value is 0.5 as required.

What is the problem in the below line of code that crashes the entire code?When executing this line of code the system breaks. Is anything missing anything in the KAMA function here or this is used completely wrong. If this should be working what shall be the right approach, please.

```
stockdata['vOpen']=ta.KAMA(np.asarray(stockdata['vClose']),hakamaper)
```

Comment: No update? it is needed , Can someone answer?